# Verb moods in the poem "Once more into the fray"

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, poetry, mood

There is a poem in the Movie "The Grey" (2011). It goes like this:

> Once more into the fray...
>   Into the last good fight I'll ever know.
>   Live and die on this day...
>   Live and die on this day...

What is the mood of the verbs *live* and *die*? Is it imperative or indicative? Or is it the infinitive, even?

I can understand the general meaning of the poem, but I´m not a native speaker. I'm not sure if I understand it the right way.

Comment: It seems to imply a first-person singular.  If we take clues from the previous sentence and apply it to the final two, then we can get: 'Into the last good fight *I'll* ever know. / (I will) live and die on this day... (etc.)'  In colloquial English it is quite common to omit the pronoun *I* from the beginning of sentences.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it is none of them.

In such cases as this (often found in poetry), English has the ability to use the base form of a verb *without* implying any specific morphological form whatsoever. This is similar to the [injunctive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injunctive_mood) found in Vedic Sanskrit and (more limited) Ancient Greek.

Basically, it's a verb form that says nothing real about mood, aspect, or tense. In English, it also says nothing about subject or voice, either.

If you wish to liken it to a morphological verbal category more established in traditional English grammars, I'd say it would be closest to an infinitive without the overt infinitive marker *to*.

Answer (score -1):

"Live and die": As these verb forms are at the beginning of a sentence they can only be imperatives. I think "Live or die" would fit better.
One could also interpret "live and/or die" as an infinitive if one understand it as: It is live and die or It is to live and die. ( I'm not sure whether in English the "to" is used or not. I suppose both variants are possible.)